# WHy support count of candidate 3-itemset "bread milk diaper" is given as 3, Apriori algorithm,

Tags: associations, data-mining, rules, apriori, mining

WHy support count of candidate 3-itemset  "bread milk diaper" is given as 3, although it appears in only 2 transctions, kindly check the apriori algorithm association mining in datamining text book by Pang-ning tan, vipin kumar and steinbach [please go trough the image for more clarity on question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XeWm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That slide does not contain the original transactions.

Try scanning the original database. You cannot get the exact counts just from the previous itemsets; you can only get upper bounds.